# Como crear el efecto "pulse" de material design en PyQt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Llevo tiempo tratando de integrar el efecto "pulse" a los botones o widgets que lo permitan pero no he podido hacerlo

Empecé a crear entornos con HTML y por atras python para poder aplicar todos los efectos necesarios

Tengo entendido que el efecto lo debo aplicar en los evento `mousePressEvent()` y `mouseReleaseEvent` pero me encuentro estancado.

Ajunto una clase boton al cual me gustaria agregarle el efecto pulse.

```
class FlatButton(QPushButton):
    """ FlatButton es un widget que hereda de atributos y metodos de QPushButton.

    Esta modificado para cumplir con el estandar Material Design.

    Forma parte de los widget admitidos en 'ButtonContainer'.

    C{Modo de uso}
        >>> flat_button = FlatButton()
    """

    def __init__(self, text=None, text_color=Gray.PrimaryText, parent=None):
        QPushButton.__init__(self, parent)
        self.__text_color = text_color

        self.setMinimumHeight(36)
        self.setMinimumWidth(72)
        self.setFont(Font(font="Roboto medium", size=13))
        if text:
            self.setText(text)
        self.setStyleSheet()

    def setGraphicsEffect(self, QGraphicsEffect=None):
        """
        Metodo bloqueado
        """
        raise AttributeError("El metodo esta deshabilitado")

    def setText(self, q_string):
        """
        Establece el texto del boton.

        C{Modo de uso}

            >>> flat_button = FlatButton()
            >>> flat_button.setText("texto")

        @param text: Texto deseado para ser visualizado en el C{FlatButton}
        @type text: C{String} o C{QString}
        """
        super(FlatButton, self).setText("   " + q_string.upper() + "   ")

    def setTextColor(self, color):
        """
        Establece el color del texto.

        C{Modo de uso}
            >>> flat_button = FlatButton()
            >>> flat_button.setTextColor(Color.Red.Primary)

        @param color: Color importado desde la libreria C{Color} de C{PyMaterial} o equivalente.
        @type color: C{Hexadecimal}
        """
        self.__text_color = color
        self.setStyleSheet()

    def setIcon(self, q_icon):
        """
        Metodo bloqueado.
        """
        raise AttributeError("El metodo esta desabilitado.")

    def setMenu(self, QMenu):
        raise AttributeError("El metodo esta deshablitado.")

    def setStyleSheet(self, q_string=None):
        """
        Sobre escribe el metodo para cambiar el estilo del widget.

        Establece el estilo del C{FlatButton}.
        """
        if q_string:
            raise AttributeError("El metodo esta deshabilitado")
        color = rgb(self.__text_color[1:])
        pressed = triplet((255 - int(round((255 - color[0]) * .48)), 255 - int(round((255 - color[1]) * .48)),
                           255 - int(round((255 - color[2]) * .48))))
        super(FlatButton, self).setStyleSheet("QPushButton {border-radius: 2px;"
                                              "background-color: %s; color: %s;} "
                                              "::disabled {color: %s;} "
                                              "::hover {background-color: %s; color: %s;} "
                                              "::focus {background-color: %s;} "
                                              "::pressed {background-color: #%s; color: %s;}"
                                              % (Transparent, self.__text_color, Gray.DisabledText,
                                                 Gray.Disabled,
                                                 self.__text_color, Gray.Disabled,
                                                 pressed, self.__text_color))
```

Comment: Hola Christopher, puedes mostrar lo que has intentado y donde te has estancado? Sobre tu codigo podemos explicarte que puedes mejorar . Un saludo (por cierto, en tu perfil leo que te gusta este *foro*. hahah no es un foro, es un *sitio* de la red [se])

Comment: adjuntare mi codigo de un boton :) (FlatButton)

Comment: Alguna idea de como hacer el efecto pulse? o de onda que se produce al precionar un componente o boton material